# Discord.py log messages when deleted

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to log messages when they were deleted using print() command. With my poor knowledge I ended up with something that looks like what is shown below.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
print(message.content + ": is deleted")
```

i want to print like "[username] deleted message in [channel]
[Message]"

I would be appreciated if you add these features to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed possible. I tried it myself, and i finally got it to work. Here's my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    msg = str(message.author)+ 'deleted message in '+str(message.channel)+': '+str(message.content)
    print(msg)
```

If you want to make a snipe command, you'll want to store the deleted message in a variable. I used a dictionary to do this, where the key was the message.channel and the value was the msg.
Hope this helps!

Comment: The message author isn't nescessarily the one who deleted it...

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to check who deleted the message with the on_message_delete event, just use an audit_logs() with limit of one, like this:

```
async def on_message_delete(message):
    async for entry in message.guild.audit_logs(limit=1,action=discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete):
        deleter = entry.user
    print(f"{deleter.name} deleted message by {message.author.name}")
```

The only problem I ran into was when someone deleted their own message, in which case it doesn't show up in the audit logs, so it gets flagged as someone else deleting it, I'm racking my brain, but no solutions come to mind. Enjoy!

Comment: UPDATE 4 May 2021: This works like a charm the mentioned issue there was that it doesn't shows the entry if the deleted is message author but it does now. Maybe it was a bug. +1

Comment: @NerdGuyAhmad it happens because when the author deletes their own message, it doesn't show up in the audit log. And my solution is based on checking the audit log for the deleter.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this tread](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/621) it's (nowadays) not possible to find the name of the user that deleted a message, you can continue to search, this tread starts to be old, maybe this functionality has been added, but I can't find it, sorry...

Comment: Looks like there is no way to get the name of the user that deleted a message... Thx for the info ^^

Comment: That thread is regarding the on_raw_message_delete.
This event is on_message_delete. The difference between the two is that on_raw_message_delete keeps track of messages that were deleted before the bot came online, while the on_message_delete keeps track of the messages deleted after the bot came online

Comment: Correct, but `on_message_delete()` doesn't give any informations about message deletion (only about the message himself), that's why I turned to `on_raw_message_delete()`
The best you can have is the message author not who deleted it, in most of the cases a message will be deleted by his author but not everytime (an admin, a moderator, a bot, can delete messages from other peoples), that's why I said it's impossible ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    print(f'message: {message.content} by {message.author} was deleted in {message.channel}')
```

i cant figure out how to see the user that deleted the message but I don't it's that important, You need to see what the message was and who sent it and what channel it was sent in so you can punish accordingly!

Enjoy (this uses Discord.py ReWrite heads up)